# angular - material table not getting populated from json array

Tags: angular, typescript

for the following code

```
public getData() {
 this.service.requestData().subscribe(res => {
  let response = JSON.stringify(res);
  let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response)
  for(let row of parsedResponse.data){
    this.dataSource.push(row)
  }
});
```

}

row elements can be displayed on console however the table that uses dataSource only shows column headers

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
public getData() {
 this.service.requestData().subscribe(res => {
  
  this.dataSource = [];
    this.dataSource =res.data;  
});
}
```

There's no need to `stringify`  and then to `reparse` the response i think .. and before fill the datasource try to clear it

Comment: Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MatTableDataSource<any[]>': _data, _renderData, _filter, _internalPageChanges, and 16 more. for line 3

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'. for line 4

Comment: are yours data inside res .. or res.data? .. try to set  this.dataSource =res;

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset your dataSource object to trigger rerendering:

```js
this.service.requestData().subscribe(res => {
  this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource, ...res.data];
});
```

MatTable accepts the `dataSource` as an input and the change detection is based on references, and pushing an element to an array will not trigger it.

**Note**

If you are using `MatTableDataSource`, set it:

```js
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the MatTable Data

```
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
```

^^ Instead of "any", you should put type of your Data.

You can create new method or you can just write this following code in ngOnInIt()

```
 this.service.requestData().subscribe(res => this.dataSource.data = res )
```

Comment: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? on second line

Comment: @hitodo9051 have you tried entering type of your object instead of "any"?